# If the Ambassador is used to take the castle in the first move, does the player then get the castle move as well?

Tags: lords-of-waterdeep

We had a hypothetical question come up (hypothetical because it wasn't actually tried) and we couldn't agree on the solution. If a player used the Ambassador to take the castle from the player currently holding it, would that player then get the castle 'first move" as well, or would it take over the next round? Some of us said that since the castle move had not yet been made, then yes, the Ambassador player would get both "first moves", and others said that no, they would proceed the next round with the castle as the first move. Which would be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly at the start of the round the player with the Ambassador who is not currently the first player assigns the Ambassador to Castle Waterdeep, thereby taking the first player marker and we want to know who's turn it is now.

I think a strict reading of the rules would make it the Ambassador player's turn.

The **Actions in a turn** section states

> Each player takes turns, one at a time, starting with the player who has the First Player marker and proceeding to that player’s left.

Castle Waterdeep

> Action: Take the First Player marker,
> and draw 1 Intrigue card.

Palace of Waterdeep

> At the start of the next round, before any other player takes a turn, assign the Ambassador.

Nothing in the rules suggests the First Player marker has memory, such as the Castle saying 'you become the first player for next round.' Or the Ambassador saying before the First Player's turn. It is entirely based on the location of the Marker when you need the information.

Interestingly the Advance Rules section clarifies what happens if you have the Ambassador and the First Player Marker. Namely that you get two turns before anyone else. But does not explicitly cover using the Ambassador to take the first player marker.